# How do I insert an object into the correct position using java?

Tags: java, sorting, insertion

My program has a catalog of objects each with things like titles, item numbers, song artists etc.  I need to take the code ive already written and change my addItem method so that it doesnt just put the item on the end of the array but instead places it in the correct spot in the array so that it stays sorted.  I am trying to do this by comparing the item type first in alphabetical order(book, movie, or music) and if those are the same i will then compare by item number.  I am not sorting the whole array after inserting the object so I know I only need one loop not two nested ones.  the only thing is that The only way ive seen of doing this is if the array itself is one of the arguments for the method,  so the method header would be something like this.

```
 public static void insertionSort (Comparable[] list)
```

however I need to do this without changing any of my method headers because if I do id then have to change them in my main method.  my add method looks like this right now.  the only parameter is the new object that is being added to the array.

```
  public void addItem(Item theItem)
    {

        items[size] = theItem;
        size++;


    }



//This Is a class for a general Item 
public class Item implements Comparable<Item>
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int itemnum;
    private String title;
    private double price;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Item
     */
    public Item(int id, String t, double p)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        itemnum = id;
        title = t;
        price = p;
    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     *
     * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
     * @return    the sum of x and y
     */
    public int getItemNumber()
    {
        // put your code here
        return itemnum;
    }

    public String getItemType()
    {
        return "Item";
    }

    public String getItemTitle()
    {
      return title;  
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String line1, line2, line3, line4, out;
        String itemtype = this.getItemType();
        line1 = String.format("Item number: %d%n", itemnum);
        line2 = String.format("Item type: %s%n", itemtype);
        line3 = String.format("Item title: %s%n", title);
        line4 = String.format("Item price: %.2f%n", price);
        out = line1 + line2 + line3 + line4 + "\n";
        return out;
    } 
    public int compareTo(Item other){
        //items are equal
        if(this.getItemType().equals(other.getItemType())){
           return this.itemnum - other.itemnum;
        }
        //item types are not equal
        else
        return this.getItemType().compareTo(other.getItemType());


    }
}
```

How do I make a method to insert an object into an array into the correct position using only the object itself as a parameter?

Comment: `Comparable` is a useless type to use directly: aside from it being raw, `new Comparable[] { 0, "" }` is legal, but it doesn't make sense to sort objects of differing types. If you want to pass an array of mutually-comparable objects, declare the method as e.g. `public static <C extends Comparable<? super C>> void insertionSort (C[] list)`

Comment: well the objects arent different types really.  they are all Items, i have other classes called music, movie, and book that extend Item

Comment: i just want to put them all in alphabetical order by type and numerical order by item number

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using LinkedList to handle the case? 1st it keeps the data ordered (insertion order by default), 2nd gives you an option to add/remove object at specific index. See below example (extracted from a quick search on Google)

```
import java.util.*;
public class JavaExample{
   public static void main(String args[]){

     LinkedList<String> list=new LinkedList<String>();

     //Adding elements to the Linked list
     list.add("Steve");
     list.add("Carl");
     list.add("Raj");

     //Adding an element to the first position
     list.addFirst("Negan");

     //Adding an element to the last position
     list.addLast("Rick");

     //Adding an element to the 3rd position
     list.add(2, "Glenn");

     //Iterating LinkedList
     Iterator<String> iterator=list.iterator();
     while(iterator.hasNext()){
       System.out.println(iterator.next());
     }
   } 
}
```

Comment: well I originally wrote this as an Arraylist program but the last assignment was to modify it so it uses an array instead of an arraylist so unfortunately I cannot use anything but an array.  literally the only thing im supposed to change is the code inside my addItem method.